# Is it possible to run a glib loop within a glib loop?

Tags: glib

Just wondering if this is possible. I have been getting response from one cycle/run of the inner loop. This is my code

```
struct app{
  GMainContext *context;
  GMainLoop *loop;
}app1;

int counter = 0;

static void
condition_responses()
{
  g_print(" counter is %d \n", counter);
  counter++;

}

static void
check_cmd()
{ 
   //// other commands

   if(some-condition)
   {
       GSource* source1 = g_timeout_source_new(1000);

       // set function to watch for command to quit
       g_source_set_callback(source,
                          (GSourceFunc)condition_responses,
                          NULL,
                          NULL);

       g_source_attach(source1, app1.context);

   }
}

int main()
{
    GSource* source = g_timeout_source_new(1000);

    // set function to watch for command to quit
    g_source_set_callback(source,
                          (GSourceFunc)check_cmd,
                          NULL,
                          NULL);

    g_source_attach(source, app1.context);

    g_main_loop_run(app1.loop);

    g_print("task ended \n");

}
```

Somehow the inner loop conditonal_responses run but it ran only for once.I would need to start some function and to run them periodically. Some question that I have

- Is this the right way to create the loop in glib?
- What other options could i go about doing them?
- What would happen if i create a g_thread to go about doing it?

Thanks

Comment: It seems like you should probably use `g_timeout_add_seconds` unless you have a particular reason you need to use the full `g_source_attach` API. Simplifying that part of the code might make it easier to see the reason why it's not working as you expect.

Comment: @ptomato it isnt working with g_timeout_add_seconds.. i have to use g_source_attach to get the first layer to be looping